# .NET APPs can't run on Windows CE 5.0

Tags: .net, windows, windows-ce

I have a device with Windows CE 5.0 with .NET CF 2.0 & 3.5 installed on it.
When i copy a .NET CF .exe file and execute it, it can't be run and shows an error :

"Cannot find 'Test2' (or one of its components)..."

what's wrong?

Comment: What references does your test need?

Comment: i have writen it by MS Visual Studio 2008 , with the type of SmartDevices C# application. it does not do anything but has a button and shows an Message Box. just this. is file copy a good way to deploy?

Comment: There should be a deploy option in VS that handles it....

Answer (score 1):

First thing to do is to remove CF 2.0 from the device.  You've not said how they are both installed, but I'll assume that you added both from the Platform Builder catalog.  Doing that actually breaks both due to a SYSGEN overlap in the build process.  You don't need both anyway, the 3.5 runtimes will load and run a 2.0 assembly with no problem.

Comment: the both .NET CF 2.0 and 3.5 was installed on it before. however i installed the .NET CF 2.0 on it again via .CAB installing method and done successfully. but the copied .NET .EXE file couldn't be run. but after it when the device was connected via USB to PC (and ActiveSync) , i deployed it by visual studio and the deployed .exe file in my device worked! i don't know why?! even when i move the deployed .exe file to another fodler in my device, it works fine. what's the matter?

Comment: The installation of both frameworks is corrupt.  When you depoloy via Studio, it pushes down and installs the framework again, fixing whatever corruption there is.  Tell your OEM to remove CF 2.0 from the device OS.

Comment: @ctacke , do you mean if .NET CF has installed correctly on a device , any copied (not deployed via Visual Studio) .NET application or library should work? is this a correct installation? BTW , when i power off my device , all deployed applications is removed after power on , and a copy of a deployed .NET app doesn't work. it seems even the correct installed .NET CF has been removed. why?

Comment: Yes, if the CF is properly installed any copied app should just run.

Comment: If you're losing the app and/or the CF after power off it's becasue you're installing to volatile memory, not persistent memory.  How to address that (and even if you can at all) is very OEM/hardware dependent.

Comment: Thank you 'ctacke', i found some related links : [application on CE device 'disappears' after power off](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssmartdevicesvbcs/thread/dc1cea2f-d04d-4586-9152-767eb9712f47/) and [Install .Net CF 3.5 cab file on NAND Flash](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winembplatdev/thread/b658cfaf-9af5-4b28-8b4e-05c41cce7ae4) that may help others, however i'll try some solutions too.